# My chat WebSockets are getting closed; what gives?

Tags: support, chat, web-sockets

I've been hunting down a bug in [Chatception](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/stackexchange-chatception) for quite a while now: sometimes messages would simply stop appearing, and I would have to refresh to make Chatception start working again.

Yesterday I finally got tired of it and decided to start logging *every single* WebSocket event (`message`, `error`, `close`) to see if any of that data could help in tracking down the bug.

Today the bug happened, so I immediately opened up my console and found:

[image: close event, gasp!]

Why are my chat WebSockets occasionally being closed (without a reason, even)? I haven't yet found a way to reliably reproduce this, but it happens at least a few times per day if I just leave a chat tab open in the background.

Here's how I'm opening the WebSocket, in case that's relevant (apologies for the terrible code):

```js
function getSock() {
    return new WebSocket(JSON.parse($.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://' + location.host + '/ws-auth',
            data: {roomid: CHAT.CURRENT_ROOM_ID,
            fkey: fkey().fkey
        }, async: false}).responseText)['url'] +
        '?l=' +
        JSON.parse($.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://' + location.host + '/chats/' + CHAT.CURRENT_ROOM_ID + '/events',
            data: {fkey: fkey().fkey},
            async: false
        }).responseText)['time']);
}
```

Comment: So you expect the websocket to stay alive forever? Is that a reasonable assumption? Are you sending hartbeats as well?

Comment: @rene I was under the impression that it *should* stay alive forever... at least, I can keep a chat window open for an indeterminate amount of time and still see new messages in realtime (perhaps the chat code itself is reopening the sockets on `close`, though). As far as I'm aware, chat doesn't require you to send heartbeats (this was "discovered" through the empirical evidence of watching Chrome DevTools for a while :P).

Comment: It will close. I recall seeing recover code in the CHAT.js, when it falls back to XHR posts on an setInterval to get events until a working Websocket is connected and  operational again.

Comment: @rene Oh, huh. It appears you're right, after [digging through the ChatExchange code (used by Smokey)](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange/blob/3f5e5bcb2ccf6e33771fc8927666f771c3580fc8/chatexchange/browser.py#L42-L49). Mind posting an answer to that effect, so I can accept it?

Comment: For the use which this appears to be written for, in-browser notification of chat events, you should probably see: [How do I get notified of events in SE chat?](https://stackapps.com/questions/8268/how-do-i-get-notified-of-events-in-se-chat), which describes how to add a callback to SE chat from within a SE chat page which gets called every time the page receives an event.

Comment: For the general issue which you've described: wanting a WebSocket which remains active, I've had good success using [ReconnectingWebSocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket), which is released under an MIT license. I have no affiliation with the project, other than that I've used it in multiple scripts/projects to solve the general issue mentioned here. That particular one hasn't been maintained in a while, but is still working. It appears there are some forks which have been updated/maintained. There are also other such packages.

Comment: @Makyen that's very useful. I've also learned how to connect the wbsocket btw. THanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Websockets are not meant to or expected to stay-alive forever.  Several reasons can occur that the sockets die, either invoked by the client, the server or somewhere in the middle.

In chat.js there is code to reopen a closed connection in the onclose event but also code to fallback to polling, basically an AJAX XHR post to /events. It looks like it keeps doing that until it re-establish a working websocket connection.